# Can you help me transform to polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

Let $S^1=\{z:|z|=1\}$. For each of the functions $f$ determine $M(f)=\sum\{|f(z)|:z\in S^1\}$, $m(f)=\inf\{|f(z)|:z\in S^1\}$, and the points $z_M$ and $z_m$ such that $|F(z_M)|=M(f)$ and $|f(z_m)|=m(f)$.

$$f(z)=\frac{z-b}{1-\bar bz}\;,\text{ where }|b|\ne 1$$

$$f(z)=\frac{z-b}{1-\bar bz}-a\;,\text{ where }|b|\ne 1\text{ and }a\ne 0$$

Translation of original title: Can you help me, I tried to transform to polar coordinates but I didn't understand the second exercise

Original Spanish:

> Sea $S^{1}=\left\lbrace  z: |z|=1\right\rbrace $.Para cada una de las funciones $f$ determine $ M(F)=sup\left\lbrace |f(z)|:z \in S^{1}\right\rbrace$,$m(f)=inf\left\lbrace|f(z)|:z \in S^{1} \right\rbrace$ y los puntos $z_{M} \ \text{y} \  z_{m} $ y  tales que $|f(z_{M})|=M(f) $ y $|f(z_{m})|=m(f)$
> $$f(z)=\dfrac{z-b}{1-\bar{b}z}\  \text{donde} \  |b| \ne 1$$
> $$ f(z)=\dfrac{z-b}{1-\bar{b}z} -a \  \  \text{donde} \  |b| \ne 1 y a \neq 0$$